# writing different types of values to the windows registry

Tags: java, install4j

Is it possible to add values to the windows registry of a type other than reg_sz? In particular I need to add reg_dwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the install4j API to do that, just set a value of type `Integer`

```
 WinRegistry.setValue(
      RegistryRoot.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
      "mykey",
      "myValue",
      new Integer(5)
 );
```

In that case the resulting type in the registry will be `REG_DWORD`.